# Is this structure thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a map of queues. Access to the map and queues must be thread safe. Data is added and removed from queues by different threads.

I implemented this structure

```
public class Structure {

private final Map<String, LinkedList<String>> queues = new HashMap<>();

public void enqueue(String id, String data) {
    LinkedList<String> queue;
    synchronized (queues) {
        queue = queues.get(id);
        if (queue == null) {
            queue = new LinkedList<>();
            queues.put(id, queue);
        }
    }
    synchronized (queue) {
        queue.add(data);
    }
}

public List<String> dequeue(String id) {
    LinkedList<String> queue;
    synchronized (queues) {
        queue = queues.get(id);
    }
    if (queue != null) {
        synchronized (queue) {
            List<String> q = new LinkedList<>(queue);
            queue.clear();
            return q;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: If this is working code and you need it reviewed, https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ might be a better fit than Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 5):

The code is not correct due to the fact that the read from the HashMap is not guarded by any lock. Thus the thread that reads data from the map it has no idea any other thread has updated it.

Also it's not efficient; your structure doesn't support both `enqueue` and `dequeue` at the same time by two threads and using two synchronized blocks is resource consuming. You might as well synchronize both methods.

A more efficient implementation would be using concurrent data structures:

```
public class Structure<K, V> {
    private final Queue<V> EMPTY_QUEUE = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
    private final Map<K, Queue<V>> queues = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public void enqueue(K id, V data) {
        Queue<V> queue = queues.computeIfAbsent(id, i -> new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>());
        queue.add(data);
    }

    public List<V> dequeue(K id) {
        Queue<V> queue = queues.getOrDefault(id, EMPTY_QUEUE);
        List<V> resp = new LinkedList<>(queue);
        queue.clear();
        return resp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not thread safe: reading the hash map in `dequeue` is not protected by a lock. You can end up trying to read while a concurrent write has the map in an inconsistent internal state.

Comment: Looks OK: neither the map nor the queues can be accessed from two different threads at the same time. You could get better performance using finer grained locks or concurrent data structures though.

Comment: Question has been changed by the OP in the meantime. Now the read access to `queues` is synchronized. It hasn't been within a synchronized block before.